# Openfire Restrict Chat Clients

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am running Openfire and I would like to restrict what chat clients are able to connect to the server.  I only want a single chat client (a custom web-based one we created) to be able to connect.

I thought there was a way to do this, but digging through the settings in the admin I'm not finding it.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a built-in feature, but you can try the Client Control plugin listed on the [Openfire Plugins page](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp).  It should give you a checklist of common clients to allow, as well as the ability to add others manually.  Just be aware that it's completely possible for someone to spoof the client identity.  From the readme:

> Note: Filtering clients that are allowed to connect to the server depends on the identity presented by the client. Therefore, a client that was modified to appear as another XMPP client may connect to the server. However, only sophisticated and knowledgeable users may be able to do such modification.